# Apply condition to the same row and row next to it in Pandas data frame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have my pandas Data where I would like to check the condition row wise and assign value to the ith and (i+1)th row, what could be the easiest way to do it.

```
x=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10))
```

I have tried like this :

```
status=np.where(x<0.5,'Y','N')
```

I would like to check each of the row if the value is less than 0.5 and assign 'Y', but if it has been assigned 'Y' in the first row, consecutive row should also have 'Y' otherwise 'N'.

Result should look like this

```
0  0.652753    N
1  0.756219    N
2  0.299177    Y
3  0.851635    *Y*
4  0.942549    N
5  0.686693    N
6  0.071128    Y
7  0.482733    Y
8  0.979321    *Y*
9  0.830639    N
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output for index 8 also by Y?

Comment: What about Row 8?  Why isn't that one Yes also?  Row 7 is Yes.

Comment: @ScottBoston If OP confirms, this becomes very easy using `df.shift`. Is that the first answer that popped to mind? :p

Comment: @coldspeed you got it. :)

Comment: Yes @ScottBoston for Row 8 also it's Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.assign(status=np.where((x<0.5) | (x.shift(1)<0.5),'Y','N'))
```

Output:

```
            status
0  0.652753      N
1  0.756219      N
2  0.299177      Y
3  0.851635      Y
4  0.942549      N
5  0.686693      N
6  0.071128      Y
7  0.482733      Y
8  0.979321      Y
9  0.830639      N
```

Comment: Here you go ~ :)